# Results in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

Tags: sql-server, index, index-tuning, dmv, nonclustered-index

I have this query below that I use to clean up indexes that are not being used anymore to reduce runtime and overhead during index maintenance and during inserts. On some tables that I've ran this against, it returns indexes with 0 scans, 0 seeks and 0 lookups and there are some indexes that just returns `NULL` on the scans, seeks, lookups column. My understanding to those `NULL`'s is that, that specific index has still not been used that's why there is no data for that index in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. That being said, whats the difference between these and those indexes that show up in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` but has 0 scans, seeks and lookups? I appreciate everyone's ideas

```
DECLARE @tblname VARCHAR(100) =  'Login' --<<<TABLE NAME HERE

SELECT CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(i.[object_id]), '.', OBJECT_NAME(i.[object_id])) AS [OBJECT NAME]
       ,CASE
           WHEN I.name IS NULL THEN
               'heap table'
           ELSE
               I.[name]
       END AS [INDEX NAME]
      , i.index_id
      , s.user_seeks +s.user_scans + s.user_lookups AS [Total Scan/seek/lookup]
      ,s.user_seeks
      , s.user_scans
      , s.user_lookups
FROM sys.indexes AS I
     LEFT JOIN  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS S
        ON  I.index_id = S.index_id
        AND I.[object_id] = S.[object_id]
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(i.[object_id], 'IsUserTable') = 1
      AND OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) = @tblname
      --AND i.index_id <>1
      ORDER BY s.user_lookups DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

If an index hasn't been touched at all since start-up, then it isn't in the result from `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. Doing an outer join to that DMV means columns you pick from it will be `NULL`. As for those that are `0`, they have been touched according to `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, since it does return a row for that index.

You should be able to verify doing a `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` without involving `sys.indexes` and see that for "the NULLs" the index isn't retured and for "the 0's" the index *is* returned and potentially some system scans etc.